# How to send create account email

Tags: magento2, email, customer-account

Using this code i have create new customer and also it will login

```
$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
$websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
$store = $storeManager->getStore();
$storeId = $store->getStoreId();

$customer = $customerFactory->create();
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId); 
$customer->setEmail($user_e); 
$customer->setFirstname($_fname); 
$customer->setLastname($_lname);

$customer->setPassword($pass);
$customer->save();

$CustomerModel->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
$CustomerModel->loadByEmail($user_e);   
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($CustomerModel);
```

Now i want to send create account email, above script is not sending create account email.

How can i send create account email? Please Reply as soon as